# How to compile Swift programs for testing on the command line

Tags: swift

I am trying to set up a Swift project on the command line, preferably for both OS X and Linux. I managed to compile Swift source to executable binaries, dynamic libraries and Swift modules on OS X. Now I am trying to get testing to work by using the XCTest framework. When I am trying to compile the testing module, the compiler tells me that my module was not "compiled for testing". While there are a lot of hints about "enabling testability" in Xcode, I couldn't find any pointers about doing this with the Swift command line compiler. So, how can do this?